# User-owned cable modem for Spectrum Internet Gig service

Tags: cable

My Spectrum cable Internet can be upgraded to 940mbps service, but I prefer to own my modem.  As of October 2018, Spectrum has stated that "There are no modems that have passed certification testing for the Spectrum Internet Gig tier with speeds up to 940 Mbps."

However, there is a list of Minimally Qualified Modems below.  I have sorted them by those that advertise DOCSIS 3.1 .

Has anyone successfully connected to Spectrum "Internet Gig" service with any of the modems below?

https://www.spectrum.net/support/internet/compliant-modems-charter-network/

Yes Arris SBG6950

Yes Arris SBG6950 AC2

Yes Netgear C3000v2

Yes Netgear C3700v2

Yes Netgear Cable Orbi CBR40 or CBK40

No Arris SBG7400
No Arris SBG7400 AC2
No Linksys CG7500
No Linksys CM3016
No Motorola MB7621
No Netgear C6220
No Netgear C6300-100NAS
No Netgear C6300 B Step v2
No Netgear C6300 D0
No Netgear C7000
??? Netgear C7000v2
No Netgear C7500
No Netgear C7500 D0
No Netgear CM700
No Netgear N450-100NAS
No TP-Link CR1900
No TP-Link TC7650
No Zoom 5370

Comment: My opinion would be DOCSIS 3.1 should be the spec you need, but if Spectrum won’t approve it on their system, the point is mute.  It sounds like the table is out-of-date, but that might be by design.  Since Title II no longer applies, are isp’s in fact still required to approve CPE (customer provided equipment)?

Comment: "Required" is a funny word, when the federal DOJ is suing my state (California) regarding related legislation, supporting the ISPs.  Oh well.

Comment: Ever notice you can buy your own cable modem, but you can only lease your set-top-box?  The reason they had to allow CPE dealt with why you don’t have to lease your phones from the phone company anymore, it all fell under title II.